# CDHtmlDialog crashes while navigating to pdf after navigating to google

Tags: html, visual-c++, mfc

Navigate from www.google.com page to pdf file causes exception in CDHtmlDialog.
This exception is not present while navigating from pages other than google (e.g. www.wikipedia.org).

Overridden "OnBeforeNavigate", "OnNavigateComplete" and "OnDocumentComplete" events. Then found that, in issue scenario, while loading pdf file  "OnNavigateComplete" is called twice.
The calling sequence is as follows: OnBeforeNavigate=>OnNavigateComplete=>OnNavigateComplete

As "OnNavigateComplete" is called without calling "OnBeforeNavigate", "m_spHtmlDoc" in CDHtmlDialog does not become NULL and validation causes assertion in "CDHtmlDialog::OnNavigateComplete".
ASSERT(m_spHtmlDoc==NULL);

Header:

```
class CClientAppDlg : public CDHtmlDialog
```

cpp:

```
CClientAppDlg::CClientAppDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
    : CDHtmlDialog(IDD_CLIENTAPP_DIALOG, 0, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CClientAppDlg::OnBnClickedNavigate()
{
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    Navigate(m_csNavURL); // Get URL from edit box and navigate
    UpdateData (FALSE);
}

void CClientAppDlg::OnBeforeNavigate( LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::OnBeforeNavigate(pDisp, szUrl);
}

void CClientAppDlg::OnNavigateComplete( LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::OnNavigateComplete(pDisp, szUrl);
}

void CClientAppDlg::OnDocumentComplete(LPDISPATCH pDisp, LPCTSTR szUrl)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::OnDocumentComplete(pDisp, szUrl);
}
```

1. Why "OnNavigateComplete" is called twice and causing exception?
2. Why does it happen only while navigating from google page?

Comment: Try to open that website in Internet Explorer. There could be bugs unrelated to MFC.

Comment: Thank you for the check point. No issue in Internet Explorer. PDF file is from local machine itself.

Comment: It looks like you are using a PDF plugin, which we can't see. Show the rest of your dialog, and also how the dialog is created. And state the version of your Visual Studio, it might be relevant. You don't need `UpdateData(TRUE)` in there, although it shouldn't cause a problem. `OnNavigateComplete` is sometimes called twice, I don't know why either, but it shouldn't cause an exception.

Comment: I am using VS2017. I created this application to find out the issue. Create a MFC dialog application and change its base class from CDialogEx to CDHtmlDialog. To use CDHtmlDialog include "afxdhtml.h" file. Replace usage of CDialogEx in cpp file with CDHtmlDialog.  In CDHtmlDialog constructor, used '0' as second parameter. These are shown in the code snippet. Add edit control to get URL. Add button and on click event navigate to URL in edit control. First give URL as "www.google.com". Then "E:\sample.pdf".  I think IE uses adobe reader as plugin. Thank you for the comments.